# Open GL shader with 2 textures

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm trying to do some experiments with `Open GL ES` on Android.

I'm trying to write a shader that got two uniform variables pointing 2 textures.
One containing the current frame, and the other containing the texture drawn on frame before

They're created in java world like this:

```
texturenames = new int[2];
GLES20.glGenTextures(2, texturenames, 0);

// Bind texture to texturename
GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texturenames[0]);
GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE1);
GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texturenames[1]);
```

Then are passed as parameters of the shader like this:

```
int location = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation (ShaderTools.program, "currentTexture" );
GLES20.glUniform1i ( location, 0 );
location = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation (ShaderTools.program, "prevFrameTexture" );
GLES20.glUniform1i ( location, 1 );
```

This is the content of the fragment shader:

```
precision mediump float;
varying vec2 v_TexCoordinate;
uniform sampler2D currentTexture;
uniform sampler2D prevFrameTexture;

main() {
    gl_FragColor   = (texture2D(currentTexture, v_TexCoordinate) +
                      texture2D(prevFrameTexture, v_TexCoordinate)) / 2;
}
```

***What i want to achieve is create a sort of blurring effect that's the result of the average of current and previous frame.***

Is it possibile to update `prevFrameTexture` directly into shader code? I didn't find any way to do this.

As alternative... how should i tackle this problem?

Should i copy the content of `currentTexture` into `prevFrameTexture` in java world?

I tried to draw alternatively the `TEXTURE0` and `TEXTURE1` into `onDrawFrame` but it doesn't work as `glActiveTexture` to swap from one to another, doesn't work inside that callback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible. Use Render To Texture (RTT)

We can make a FBO as a texture so you should make two FBOs.
An example of making a RTT below

```
glGenFramebuffers(1, &fbo[object_id]);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo[object_id]);

glGenRenderbuffers(1, &rboColor[object_id]);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, rboColor[object_id]);
```

Right after, make a texture following code below

```
glGenTextures(1, &texture[texture_id].texture_id);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[texture_id].texture_id);

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, texture_width, texture_height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[texture_id].texture_id, 0);
```

Once you have RTT textures, you can update these by rendering each framebuffer

https://github.com/sunglab/StarEngine/blob/master/renderer/StarFBO.cpp

void StarFBO::createFBO(...)

https://github.com/sunglab/StarEngine/blob/master/renderer/StarTexture.cpp

void StarTexture::createTEXTURE_RTT(...)